# I am trying to advance to a new information each time someone signs up on my java application

Tags: java, file-writing

So everytime someone clicks sign up on my program, I call a method that opens file and adds record.
This is to open the file:

```
try {
    l = new Formatter("chineses.txt");
    System.out.println("Did create");
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Did not create");
}

public void addRecord(){ //This is how i add the record
    l.format("%s", nameField.getText());
}
```

Everytime I put in a name in the name field and click sign up in my gui, it always replaces whatever is on the first line in the text file.
How can I make it go to the second line while retaining what is on the first line each time someone else puts their name and clicks sign up?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create the object of `FileWriter` and pass it to the `Formatter`. It will append your text in the File.

Try this code:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("chineses.txt",true);
l = new Formatter(writer);

public void addRecord(){ //This is how i add the record
    l.format("%s\n", nameField.getText());
}
```